# Postgres request too long on date

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres and i have a request that take too much time.

Here is the request :

```
select mytable.id as id1_432_ 
from mytable mytable 
cross join mytable2 mytable2 
where mytable.moLine_id=mytable2.id 
and mytable2.realline_id = 570
and mytable.type='DONE' 
and mytable.effectiveAt<='2020-01-06'
and (mytable.effectiveAt is null or mytable.effectiveAt>='2020-01-04') 
and mytable.isCancelled=false 
order by mytable.createdAt asc
limit 10;
```

but this request take too much time, about 5 seconds.

Here is the table and index definition:

```
         Colonne          |              Type              | Collationnement | NULL-able | Par défaut 
    ---------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------
     id                        | bigint                         |                 | not null  | 
     createdat                 | timestamp without time zone    |                 |           | 
     iscancelled               | boolean                        |                 | not null  | 
     type                      | character varying(255)         |                 |           | 
     moline_id                 | bigint                         |                 | not null  | 
     effectiveat               | timestamp(6) without time zone |                 |        


     \d test_index_2
                   Index « test_index_2 »
   Colonne   |              Type              | Clé ? | Définition  
    -------------+--------------------------------+-------+-------------
     type        | character varying(255)         | oui   | type
     iscancelled | boolean                        | oui   | iscancelled
     createdat   | timestamp without time zone    | oui   | createdat
     effectiveat | timestamp(6) without time zone | oui   | effectiveat
     id          | bigint                         | non   | id
btree, pour la table « mytable »
```

Here the explain plan :

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.71..592.03 rows=10 width=16) (actual time=2039.456..2039.458 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1948148 read=85274
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..8117326.12 rows=137276 width=16) (actual time=2039.454..2039.456 rows=0 loops=1)
     Buffers: shared hit=1948148 read=85274
     ->  Index Scan using test_index_2 on mytable mytable1  (cost=0.43..4580629.13 rows=544778 width=24) (actual time=1962.026..2036.599 rows=2044 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (((type)::text = 'DONE'::text) AND (iscancelled = false) AND (effectiveat <= '2020-01-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
           Filter: ((effectiveat IS NULL) OR (effectiveat >= '2020-01-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
           Rows Removed by Filter: 2963978
           Buffers: shared hit=1942021 read=85269
     ->  Index Scan using sys_c001197805 on mytable2 mytable2  (cost=0.28..6.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=2044)
           Index Cond: (id = mytable1.moline_id)
           Filter: (realline_id = 570)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
           Buffers: shared hit=6127 read=5
 Planning Time: 0.548 ms
 Execution Time: 2039.513 ms
```

the explainplan show this **Index Scan using test_index_2 on mytable mytable1  (cost=0.43..4580629.13 rows=544778 width=24)**

And for information:

```
select count(*) from mytable ;
count  
---------
 3652331

# select count(*) from mytable2;
 count 
-------
  5417
```

How can I optimize this request by adding a good index?

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: Also, your explain plan includes a limit that doesn't exist in your query.

Comment: The `IS NULL OR` is redundant in `effectiveAt<='2020-01-06' and (mytable.effectiveAt is null or mytable.effectiveAt>='2020-01-04')`.  If it meets the <= condition, it can't be null.  I'm surprised the planner isn't smart enough to toss that out, but apparently it is not.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i change the explain with analyze buffers

Comment: @Jeremy i omit to add limit but it exist, and i modify my query

Comment: @jjanes, yes it s an autogenerated query, i think postgres is smart enough to see this and during its rewriter phase he change this to have correct query, i can change it but it doesn't change anything on the time...

Comment: If you remove the `mytable.effectiveAt is null or`, the query will become faster.

Answer (score 0):

It thinks it will find 137276 rows, but really finds 0.  So it likes to read the index in order of createdAt, so that it can avoid sorting 137276 rows and it can stop early (it thinks after 10/137276 of the scan).  But it is very wrong, as it has to scan the entire chunk of the index that meets `type = 'DONE' AND (iscancelled = false)`, which is most of it the index.  And the avoided sort would really be of 0 rows, which doesn't take enough time to be worth avoiding.

A better index would be one swapping the order of the createdAt and effectiveAt columns.  That way it could apply the effectivAt condition to restrict the part of the index it would need to scan.  But for this to work optimally, you would have to get rid of the useless `...IS NULL OR...` as PostgreSQL isn't smart enough to discard it.  Also, if you have both indexes, the bad row count estimation might still lead it to choose the wrong one.

Another improvement would be to add moline_id to the end of the index.  That way you could get an index-only-scan which would avoid a lot of random IO looking up table rows in a (presumably) random-IO fashion.  This could improve things independent of whether you also swap the order of the other columns, and this alone might be enough to make the query fast enough, if the table is well-vacuumed.